# How to pass arguments to a subroutine in template toolkit function

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I my document *foo.tt* i would like to write something like this:

```
[% INCLUDE header('str', 1, 2, 3, 5, 10) %]
```

My aim is to do some string manipulation on *str* and then with *foreach* / *for* iterates over all the numbers.

unfortunately i was unable to find that this type of syntax in Template toolkit is allowed.

What is Template toolkit way for passing arguments to a subroutine?

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass arguments, but you need to give them names.  Example:

outer.tt2:

```
[% INCLUDE header.tt2 header_string="str", items=[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 10 ] -%]
```

header.tt2:

```
String: [% header_string %]
[% FOREACH item IN items -%]
Item: [% item %]
[% END -%]
```

output:

```
String: str
Item: 1
Item: 2
Item: 3
Item: 5
Item: 10
```

Comment: what does the "-" at the end of [% INCLUDE ... line means?

Comment: It directs TT to chomp the whitespace: http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Syntax.html#section_Chomping_Whitespace

Comment: @ysth, does the file need have the suffix tt2? or can it have the suffix tt?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`MACRO`](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_MACRO) definitions:

```
[% MACRO header(str, items) BLOCK -%]
    [% FOREACH i IN items; -%]
 ... your item code here ... 
    [% END -%]
[% END -%]

[% header('str',[1, 2, 3, 5, 10]) %]
```

If TT exposed the raw arguments list at the template level, you could call it as you indicated (e.g. `header('str', 1, 2, 3, 5, 10)`), but this is pretty close.